# Having trouble running Flask app under uWSGI

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I am trying to run my Flask app under uWSGI and am getting:

```
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
```

The layout is:

```
/opt/myapp
/opt/myapp/wsgi.py
/opt/myapp/run.py
/opt/myapp/lib
/opt/myapp/app
/opt/myapp/app/blueprints.py
/opt/myapp/app/filters
/opt/myapp/app/filters/__init__.py
/opt/myapp/app/__init__.py
/opt/myapp/app/main.py
```

`app/__init__.py` contains the usual:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

`app/main.py` looks like:

```
import blueprints
import filters

from app import app

def run(debug, host='0.0.0.0'):
    app.run(debug=debug, host=host)
```

`wsgi.py` looks like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from app.main import app as application
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

If I run `python wsgi.py` from the CLI, it works fine, the usual `:5000` server.

If I run:

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8080 --protocol=http -w wsgi
```

I see the error, it cannot load the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uWSGI **imports** your `wsgi.py`. So this code is never executed:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from app.main import app as application
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

You should create the application at module level:

```
from app.main import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(...)
```

You must of course leave the `.run()` method inside the main block, because you don't want uWSGI to execute that.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like ...

`uwsgi -s 0.0.0.0:8080 --protocol=http --module myapp --callable app`

I'm not 100% sure the --module and --callable options are correct, because I don't have your actual code in front of me, might be something like --module myapp.app --callable main or some other variant

From the documentation on using uwsgi together.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/uwsgi/

Answer (score -1):

If it's in virtualenv You have to activate it by adding:

```
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

And I think You should define project directory:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/opt/myapp/app')
```